# Qt QML Settings.hasTouchScreen returns false

Tags: qml, touch, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to find out why flicking is not working with a `TreeView` example on my Raspberry Pi3 with touch screen.

Looking at the qml code of `TreeView.qml`, e.g.
https://github.com/RSATom/Qt/blob/master/qtquickcontrols/src/controls/TreeView.qml:

```
BasicTableView {
...
    __mouseArea: MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea

        parent: __listView
        width: __listView.width
        height: __listView.height
        z: -1
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        focus: true
        // If there is not a touchscreen, keep the flickable from eating our mouse drags.
        // If there is a touchscreen, flicking is possible, but selection can be done only by tapping, not by dragging.
        preventStealing: !Settings.hasTouchScreen
        ...
     }
}
```

By similarly looking at the qml code for `BasicTableView.qml`, it seems that behavior is controlled by `Settings.hasTouchScreen`.

According to:
https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtquickcontrols/src/controls/Private/qquickcontrolsettings.cpp.html
it corresponds to the following method:

```
bool QQuickControlSettings1::hasTouchScreen() const
{
    const auto devices = QTouchDevice::devices();
    for (const QTouchDevice *dev : devices)
        if (dev->type() == QTouchDevice::TouchScreen)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

However, in my case, `Settings.hasTouchScreen` returns false; i.e. the touch screen (although working for the rest), is not
correctly detected by the QML environment, which probably explains why the flicking does not work.

According to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchdevice.html, my touch device should have been registered somehow by the private `QWindowSystemInterface::registerTouchDevice()` method, but wasn't.

How can I get this to work?
Thanks!

Comment: What does `QTouchDevice::devices()` return for you?

Comment: When I perform the check in my `main()`, `QTouchDevice::devices().length()` returns 0.

Comment: And the touch screen works for other applications? If so, it sounds like there is some issue with whatever input system Qt is configured to use on that device.

Comment: Actually, the touch works for all Qt examples and also for my current application. Only, the `TreeView` does not flick upon swiping, as expected. That's why I looked into the QML code for that element and found that `Settings.hasTouchScreen` does not return 'true' as expected, which is strange, since the touch is working indeed. I tried for example using the [QML Filebrowser example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols1-filesystembrowser-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

It seems not to work correctly with `tslib`, but works by using the `evdevtouch` plugin which is enabled by adding the following command line arguments when launching the program:

```
-plugin evdevtouch:/dev/input/eventX
```

where `eventX` is the event assigned to the touch input.

With that, `QTouchDevice::devices()` is no longer empty, and the flicking of the `TreeView` works.